# Get first real line from procedure using ProcBodyLine

Tags: vba

I am using ProcBodyLine to get the first line of a procedure to dynamically insert code at run-time in some procedure. The code I am using is the same I wrote [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677737/automatically-execute-code-before-and-after-running-any-procedure/)

I am facing an issue with procedures that have a definition in multiple lines using the "_" separator:

This is the procedure before the change:
[image: Before]

And this is the result after the code is inserted:
[image: After]

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251720(v=office.15).aspx) is very clear about ProcBodyLine: **The first line of a procedure is the line on which the Sub, Function, or Property statement appears.** But it does not says anything on how to get where the statement ends.

When the definition is using just 1 line, there is no issue at all. There is a way to know the real first code line (not definition) and get the following result?

[image: Wanted]

Comment: Can you not return the last three characters of the first line and check whether  they are `, _`? If they are you want to combine the first line with the second ( or even possibly 3rd and so on...). BTW. that syntax in RED in your screenshot itself seems a bit off to me...

Comment: Yes, actually I have that solution but I was wondering if there is any official function/way to do it.

Comment: Official? hm.. probably not.

Answer (score 0):

VBA does not allow inline comments after the continuation symbol, and the line continuation symbol must have a space before it, so if the ProcBodyLine line ends with a space and a `_`, it is a continuation line. This is true even if the procedure has a signature on a single line that ends with a comment and the continuation symbol, because in that case it will be continuation of the comment.

```
'I don't know why declaring CodeModule as VBIDE.CodeModule causes a type mismatch
Public Function GetFirstLineAfterSignature(ByVal CodeModule As Object, ByVal ProcName As String, ByVal ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind) As Long
  GetFirstLineAfterSignature = CodeModule.ProcBodyLine(ProcName, ProcKind)

  Do While Right$(CodeModule.Lines(GetFirstLineAfterSignature, 1), 2) = " _"
    GetFirstLineAfterSignature = GetFirstLineAfterSignature + 1
  Loop

  GetFirstLineAfterSignature = GetFirstLineAfterSignature + 1
End Function
```